eclipse: command line to startup (and auto create workspace) then exit?
I did some stackoverflow searching on this question, but didn't see an answer which fits my scenario.
I want to programmatically (with a script) tweak some settings in the eclipse workspace .metadata files, to change some default variables/settings to make life easier on our developers. But it requires the workspace to exist first. I want - via command line - to create the default eclipse workspace and then I can tweak things.
I am looking for the command-line equivalent of:

start up eclipse (eclipse auto-creates the workspace files)
exit eclipse

I found examples to import a project, etc. But nothing to do a simple invoke followed by an exit without user intervention.
I such a thing possible?

That's what Eclipse Oomph is for: see blog post and wiki.
